# Open another swing gui after clicking a button in another swing gui

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I would like to open another swing gui after clicking a button and I cannot figure the code out to do it here the main gui  that has the button in it:

```
   /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication1;
import static java.lang.System.out;
/**
 *
 * @author Matthew
 */
public class NewFrame extends java.awt.Frame {
/**
 * Creates new form NewFrame
 */
public NewFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");

    addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
            exitForm(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setText("jButton2");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jButton2.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            form(evt);
        }
    });
    add(jButton2, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

/**
 * Exit the Application
 */
private void exitForm(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                          
    System.exit(0);
}                         

private void form(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

}

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    out.println("print something");
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new NewFrame().setVisible(true);
        }

    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
// End of variables declaration
}
```

and here the file I want dialog gui that I want to open when I click on the button:

```
    /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication1;

/**
 *
 * @author Matthew
 */
public class NewJDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {
/**
 * Creates new form NewJDialog
 */
public NewJDialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();
}



/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("IT WORKS");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(72, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 318, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(128, 128, 128)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 75, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(97, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /*
     * Set the Nimbus look and feel
     */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /*
     * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
     * default look and feel. For details see
     * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /*
     * Create and display the dialog
     */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            NewJDialog dialog = new NewJDialog(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
            dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
// End of variables declaration
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to create the NewJDialog when you need it, passing in the parent window into its constructor, and then set it visible via `setVisible(true)`.  But you don't want the original window to be a Frame, which is part of the old AWT library, but rather it should be a JFrame, the equivalent class from the Swing library.

If you have any questions about this advice, please ask!